# Having difficulty passing $_GET['id'] value to javascript function, then <a href=""></a>

Tags: php, javascript

I have found some posts on this but hit a wall while trying to implement it

I have a page that looks like this

```
 results.php?id=7
```

I would like to grab the value of ?id=

I have set up a variable in my js that looks like this

```
 id: "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>",
```

But when I try and add the id to the a href if seems to break my js altogether

Here is how my

```
 <a href="raw.php?id='+id+'">copy</a>
```

How can I pass the value of $_GET['id'] to the variable id: and then add it to my a href="raw.php?id="

Here is the js I cam using it is for syntax highlighting

```
 /*
 * jQuery Highlight Plugin
 * Examples and documentation at: http://demo.webcodingstudio.com/highlight/
 * Copyright (c) 2010 E. Matsakov
 * Version: 1.0 (26-FEB-2010)
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 * Requires: jQuery v1.2.6 or later
 */
 (function($){
$.fn.highlight = function(element_params){

    var defaults = {
        // show source code tab
        source: false,
        // show zebra
        zebra: true,
        //indents: "tabs" or "space"  
        indent: 'tabs',
        //ordered or unordered list
        list: 'ol',
        //grab id
        id: "<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>",
        //name of the tag attribute to add a special language highlighting
        attribute: 'lang'
    }

    var params = $.extend({}, defaults, element_params);

    return this.each(function(){
        var code_container = $(this);
        var code_class = $(code_container).attr('class');
        var code_lang = $(code_container).attr(params.attribute);
        var code_lang_class = '';
        if(code_lang!='') {
            code_lang_class = ' '+code_lang;
        } 
        $(code_container).wrap('<div class="highlight'+code_lang_class+'"></div>');
        var highlight_container = $(code_container).parent();

        var source = code_container.html();
        source = source.replace(/</gm, '&lt;');

        //replace tabs with spaces
        if(params.indent=='space') {
            source = source.replace(/\t/g,'    ');
        }

        var code = source;

        var raw = code_container.html();
        raw = raw.replace(/</gm, '&lt;');
        if(params.indent=='space') {
            raw = raw.replace(/\t/g,'    ');
        }

        //hightlight
        switch(code_lang) {
            case 'html':
                code = $.highlightCode.hightlight_html(code);   
                break;
            case 'css':
                code = $.highlightCode.hightlight_css(code);    
                break;
            case 'php':
                code = $.highlightCode.hightlight_php(code);    
                break;
            case 'sql':
                code = $.highlightCode.hightlight_sql(code);    
                break;
            default:
                code = $.highlightCode.hightlight(code);    
                break;
        }

        code = code.replace(/(?:\r\n?|\n)$/, '');
        code = '<'+params.list+'><li>'+code.split(/\r\n|\n/).join('\n</li><li>')+'\n</li></'+params.list+'>';

        //add source and tabs
        if(params.source==true) {
            source = '<pre class="source">'+source+'</pre>';
            var tabs = '<ul class="tabs"><a href="raw.php?id='+id+'" target="_blank">copy</a></ul>';                
            $(code_container).after(source);
            $(code_container).before(tabs);
        }

        //init tabs
        if(params.source==true) {
            var tabs = $(highlight_container).find('ul.tabs li');
            $.each(tabs , function(i,tab){
                $(tab).click(function() {
                    $(tabs).removeClass('active');
                    var tab_class = $(tab).attr('class');
                    $(highlight_container).find('pre[class!="'+tab_class+'"]').css('display', 'none');
                    $(highlight_container).find('pre[class^="'+tab_class+'"]').css('display', 'block');
                    $(tab).addClass('active');
                });
            });

        }

        //replace instead of html, because of IE bug
        $(code_container).replaceWith('<pre class="'+code_class+'">'+code+'</pre>');

        //zebra
        if(params.zebra==true) {
            $(highlight_container).find('pre[class="'+code_class+'"] '+params.list+' li:even').addClass('even');
        }
    });
};

$.highlightCode = {

    //DEFAULT
    hightlight: function(code) {

        var comments        = [];   // store comments

        code = code
            //replace keywords
            .replace(/(var|function|typeof|new|return|if|for|in|while|break|do|continue|case|switch)([^a-z0-9\$_])/gi,'<span class="kwd">$1</span>$2')
            //replace keywords
            .replace(/(\{|\}|\]|\[|\|)/gi,'<span class="kwd">$1</span>')
            //replace strings
            .replace(/('.*?')/g,'<span class="str">$1</span>')
            //replace multiline comments
            .replace(/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//g, function(m, t)
                { return '\0C'+push(comments, multiline_comments(m))+'\0'; })
            .replace(/\0C(\d+)\0/g, function(m, i)
                { return comments[i]; })
            //replace one line comments
            .replace(/\/\/(.*$)/gm,'<span class="com">//$1</span>')
            //replace functons
            .replace(/([a-z\_\$][a-z0-9_]*)\(/gi,'<span class="fnc">$1</span>(');
        return code;
    },

    //PHP
    hightlight_php: function(code) {

        var comments        = [];   // store comments

        var funcs   =   'abs acos acosh addcslashes addslashes ' +
            'array_change_key_case array_chunk array_combine array_count_values array_diff '+
            'array_diff_assoc array_diff_key array_diff_uassoc array_diff_ukey array_fill '+
            'array_filter array_flip array_intersect array_intersect_assoc array_intersect_key '+
            'array_intersect_uassoc array_intersect_ukey array_key_exists array_keys array_map '+
            'array_merge array_merge_recursive array_multisort array_pad array_pop array_product '+
            'array_push array_rand array_reduce array_reverse array_search array_shift '+
            'array_slice array_splice array_sum array_udiff array_udiff_assoc '+
            'array_udiff_uassoc array_uintersect array_uintersect_assoc '+
            'array_uintersect_uassoc array_unique array_unshift array_values array_walk '+
            'array_walk_recursive atan atan2 atanh base64_decode base64_encode base_convert '+
            'basename bcadd bccomp bcdiv bcmod bcmul bindec bindtextdomain bzclose bzcompress '+
            'bzdecompress bzerrno bzerror bzerrstr bzflush bzopen bzread bzwrite ceil chdir '+
            'checkdate checkdnsrr chgrp chmod chop chown chr chroot chunk_split class_exists '+
            'closedir closelog copy cos cosh count count_chars date decbin dechex decoct '+
            'deg2rad delete ebcdic2ascii echo empty end ereg ereg_replace eregi eregi_replace error_log '+
            'error_reporting escapeshellarg escapeshellcmd eval exec exit exp explode extension_loaded '+
            'feof fflush fgetc fgetcsv fgets fgetss file_exists file_get_contents file_put_contents '+
            'fileatime filectime filegroup fileinode filemtime fileowner fileperms filesize filetype '+
            'floatval flock floor flush fmod fnmatch fopen fpassthru fprintf fputcsv fputs fread fscanf '+
            'fseek fsockopen fstat ftell ftok getallheaders getcwd getdate getenv gethostbyaddr gethostbyname '+
            'gethostbynamel getimagesize getlastmod getmxrr getmygid getmyinode getmypid getmyuid getopt '+
            'getprotobyname getprotobynumber getrandmax getrusage getservbyname getservbyport gettext '+
            'gettimeofday gettype glob gmdate gmmktime in_array ini_alter ini_get ini_get_all ini_restore ini_set '+
            'interface_exists intval ip2long is_a is_array is_bool is_callable is_dir is_double '+
            'is_executable is_file is_finite is_float is_infinite is_int is_integer is_link is_long '+
            'is_nan is_null is_numeric is_object is_readable is_real is_resource is_scalar is_soap_fault '+
            'is_string is_subclass_of is_uploaded_file is_writable is_writeable mkdir mktime nl2br '+
            'parse_ini_file parse_str parse_url passthru pathinfo readlink realpath rewind rewinddir rmdir '+
            'round str_ireplace str_pad str_repeat str_replace str_rot13 str_shuffle str_split '+
            'str_word_count strcasecmp strchr strcmp strcoll strcspn strftime strip_tags stripcslashes '+
            'stripos stripslashes stristr strlen strnatcasecmp strnatcmp strncasecmp strncmp strpbrk '+
            'strpos strptime strrchr strrev strripos strrpos strspn strstr strtok strtolower strtotime '+
            'strtoupper strtr strval substr substr_compare';

        var keywords =  'and or xor array as break case ' +
            'cfunction const continue declare default die do else ' +
            'elseif enddeclare endfor endforeach endif endswitch endwhile ' +
            'extends for foreach function include include_once global if ' +
            'new old_function return static switch use require require_once ' +
            'while abstract interface public implements extends private protected throw';

        funcs = new RegExp(get_keywords(funcs), 'gi');
        keywords = new RegExp(get_keywords(keywords), 'gi');

        code = code
            //replace strings
            .replace(/(".*?")/g,'<span class="str">$1</span>')
            .replace(/('.*?')/g,'<span class="str">$1</span>')  
            //replace multiline comments
            .replace(/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//g, function(m, t)
                { return '\0C'+push(comments, multiline_comments(m))+'\0'; })
            .replace(/\0C(\d+)\0/g, function(m, i)
                { return comments[i]; })
            //replace one line comments
            .replace(/\/\/(.*$)/gm,'<span class="com">//$1</span>')
            //replace variables
            .replace(/\$(\w+)/g,'<span class="var">$$$1</span>')
            //replace functions
            .replace(funcs,'<span class="fnc">$1</span>$2')
            //replace keywords
            .replace(keywords,'<span class="kwd">$1</span>$2');
        return code;
    },

    //CSS
    hightlight_css: function(code) {

        var comments        = [];   // store comments

        var keywords =  'background-color background-image background-position ' +
            'background-repeat background border-collapse border-color border-spacing border-style border-top ' +
            'border-right border-bottom border-left border-top-color border-right-color border-bottom-color border-left-color ' +
            'border-top-style border-right-style border-bottom-style border-left-style border-top-width border-right-width ' +
            'border-bottom-width border-left-width border-width border color cursor direction display ' +
            'float font-size-adjust font-family font-size font-stretch font-style font-variant font-weight font ' +
            'height left letter-spacing line-height list-style-image list-style-position list-style-type list-style margin-top ' +
            'margin-right margin-bottom margin-left margin max-height max-width min-height min-width ' +
            'outline-color outline-style outline-width outline overflow padding-top padding-right padding-bottom padding-left padding position' +
            'quotes right size src table-layout text-align top text-decoration text-indent text-shadow text-transform ' +
            'vertical-align visibility white-space width word-spacing x-height z-index';

        var values =    'absolute all attr auto baseline behind below black blink block blue bold bolder '+
            'both bottom capitalize caption center center-left center-right circle close-quote collapse compact '+
            'continuous cursive dashed decimal default digits disc dotted double embed expanded fixed format '+
            'gray green groove help hidden hide high higher icon inline-table inline inset inside invert italic '+
            'justify large larger left-side left leftwards level line-through list-item '+
            'lowercase lower low ltr marker medium middle move none no-repeat normal nowrap oblique olive once outset '+
            'outside overline pointer print purple red relative repeat repeat-x repeat-y rgb right rtl screen scroll show silver slower slow '+
            'small small-caps small-caption smaller soft solid square s-resize static sub super '+
            'table-caption table-cell table-column table-column-group table-footer-group table-header-group table-row table-row-group '+
            'text-bottom text-top thick thin top transparent underline upper-alpha uppercase upper-latin '+
            'upper-roman url visible wait white wider w-resize x-fast x-high x-large x-low x-small x-soft yellow';

        var fonts =     '[mM]onospace [tT]ahoma [vV]erdana [aA]rial [hH]elvetica [sS]ans-serif [sS]erif [cC]ourier New mono sans serif';

        keywords = new RegExp(get_keywords(keywords), 'gi');
        values = new RegExp(get_keywords(values), 'gi');
        fonts = new RegExp(get_keywords(fonts), 'gi'); 

        code = code
            //replace comments
            .replace(/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//g, function(m, t)
                { return '\0C'+push(comments, multiline_comments(m))+'\0'; })
            .replace(/\0C(\d+)\0/g, function(m, i)
                { return comments[i]; })        
            //replace keywords
            .replace(keywords,'<span class="kwd">$1</span>$2')
            //replace values
            .replace(values,'<span class="pln">$1</span>$2')
            //replace fonts
            .replace(fonts,'<span class="str">$1</span>$2')
            //replace hex colors
            .replace(/(\#[a-fA-F0-9]{3,6})/gi,'<span class="lit">$1</span>')
            //replace sizes
            .replace(/(-?\d+)(\.\d+)?(px|em|pt|\:|\%|)/gi,'<span class="lit">$1$3</span>');
        return code;
    },

    //HTML
    hightlight_html: function(code) {

        code = code
            //replace attributes
            .replace(/\s+([a-zA-Z\-]{0,15})\=\"([-a-z0-9_ \/\.\#\:\=\;]{0,49})\"/gi,' <span class="atn">$1</span>=<span class="atv">"$2"</span>')
            //replace open tags
            .replace(/(&lt;)(\w{0,15})(\s+|&gt;|>)/gi,'$1<span class="tag">$2</span>$3')
            //replace close tags
            .replace(/(&lt;)\/(\w{0,15})(&gt;|>)/gi,'$1/<span class="tag">$2</span>$3')
            //replace doctype
            .replace(/(&lt;!)([-a-z0-9_ \/\.\#\:\"]{0,150})(&gt;|>)/gi,'<span class="dec">$1$2$3</span>')       
            //replace comments
            .replace(/(&lt;|<)!--([\s\S]*?)--(&gt;|>)/gm,'<span class="com">$1!--$2--$3</span>');

        return code;
    },

    //SQL
    hightlight_sql: function(code) {
        var comments        = [];   // store comments

        var funcs   =   'abs avg case cast coalesce convert count current_timestamp ' +
                    'current_user day isnull left lower month nullif replace right ' +
                    'session_user space substring sum system_user upper user year';

        var keywords =  'absolute action add after alter as asc at authorization begin bigint ' +
                    'binary bit by cascade char character check checkpoint close collate ' +
                    'column commit committed connect connection constraint contains continue ' +
                    'create cube current current_date current_time cursor database date ' +
                    'deallocate dec decimal declare default delete desc distinct double drop ' +
                    'dynamic else end end-exec escape except exec execute false fetch first ' +
                    'float for force foreign forward free from full function global goto grant ' +
                    'group grouping having hour ignore index inner insensitive insert instead ' +
                    'int integer intersect into is isolation key last level load local max min ' +
                    'minute modify move name national nchar next no numeric of off on only ' +
                    'open option order out output partial password precision prepare primary ' +
                    'prior privileges procedure public read real references relative repeatable ' +
                    'restrict return returns revoke rollback rollup rows rule schema scroll ' +
                    'second section select sequence serializable set size smallint static ' +
                    'statistics table temp temporary then time timestamp to top transaction ' +
                    'translation trigger true truncate uncommitted union unique update values ' +
                    'varchar varying view when where with work';

        var op =    'all and any between cross in join like not null or outer some';

        funcs = new RegExp(get_keywords(funcs), 'gi');
        keywords = new RegExp(get_keywords(keywords), 'gi');
        op = new RegExp(get_keywords(op), 'gi');

        code = code
            //replace strings
            .replace(/(".*?")/g,'<span class="str">$1</span>')
            .replace(/('.*?')/g,'<span class="str">$1</span>')  
            //replace multiline comments
            .replace(/\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//g, function(m, t)
                { return '\0C'+push(comments, multiline_comments(m))+'\0'; })
            .replace(/\0C(\d+)\0/g, function(m, i)
                { return comments[i]; })
            //replace one line comments
            .replace(/\/\/(.*$)/gm,'<span class="com">//$1</span>')
            //replace variables
            .replace(/\$(\w+)/g,'<span class="var">$$$1</span>')
            //replace functions
            .replace(funcs,'<span class="fnc">$1</span>$2')
            //replace keywords
            .replace(keywords,'<span class="kwd">$1</span>$2')
            //replace operators
            .replace(op,'<span class="op">$1</span>$2');
        return code;
    }
};

/*
* helpers
*/

//prepare regexp template for keywords
function get_keywords(str)
{
    return '(' + str.replace(/ /g, '|') + ')([^a-z0-9\$_])';
}

//process multiline comments
function multiline_comments(text)
{
    text    = text.split('\n');
    for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
        text[i] = '<span class="com">'+text[i]+'</span>';
    }
    return text.join('\n');
}

//add element, return index
function push(array, element)
{
    array.push(element);
    return array.length-1;
}   

 })(jQuery);
```

EDIT 2

the reason I want this is the js is used to highlight the syntax and I have added a copy button the strips out all the highlighting an opens the code into a new blank page, I just need the id to match so it knows what item to retrieve from the database

Seems like every time I add the ' ' it breaks the rest of the js and removes the copy button and syntax highlighting

You can check out the demo here, it may be easier to see

[SITE](http://ondrovic.no-ip.org/site/results.php?id=8)

EDIT 3

I can't seem to pass the value of ?id=7 to the js varaible, its frustrating not being able to verbalize what I am trying to do

Even when using

```
<a href="raw.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">copy</a>
```

it never actually grabs the value of 'id'

EDIT 4:

I scrapped this as I couldn't get it to work via js but I did get it to correctly work via php using the following code

```
 $n = $_GET['id'];
 echo '<a class="copy" href="raw.php?id='.$n.'" target="_blank">copy</a>'."\n";
```

Comment: You can't do it that way, id means nothing inside your html if it's not sorrounded by script tags.

Comment: Please share the full JavaScript code; what you have shown so far is difficult to answer.

Comment: Is it a `js` file. Is it *processed* by php ?

Answer (score 1):

The same way you echo it.  Note that your code isn't setting up a variable like you assume... you're just displaying it.  `<a href="raw.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">copy</a>`

Answer (score 1):

why not get it by JavaScript like

```
var ID_url = getUrlVars()["id"];

function getUrlVar() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, 

      function(m,key,value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like he's trying to construct a link given an id passed in to the page.  I don't think he wants a client-side solution, though I could be wrong.

Comment: Is there any reason to do it this way when you're already using PHP?

Comment: @EliGassert if the parameter in url is set then it would work too

Comment: Nope you're correct, he edited the Q it seems and says that he's setting it up in JS, so where I was assuming he was just echo'ing an `id` for verification, it looks like he might be outputting that as a part of a JSON document.  My mistake!

Comment: the reason I want this is the js is used to highlight the syntax and I have added a copy button the strips out all the highlighting an opens the code into a new blank page, I just need the id to match so it knows what item to retrieve from the database

Comment: you mean you have id in url and you want to get id and highlight the syntax ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 <?php echo "<a href=\"raw.php?id='$id'\">copy</a>"; ?>
```

Or:

```
 <?php echo "<a href=\"raw.php?id='".$id."'\">copy</a>"; ?>
```

Comment: And missing the fact that the HTML isn't wrapped in PHP, so that won't do anything anyway.  EDIT: looks like the answer was changed to be proper PHP.

Answer (score -2):

Without echoing with PHP the `$id` inside every `a` (as other answers suggest), you could use some `jQuery`:

```
var id = <?php echo ($_GET['id']?$_GET['id']:''); ?>;

$(document).ready(function()}
    $('a').attr('href', function(i, val){
        return val+'?id='+id;
    });
});
```

Change `a` with the proper selector for your links.

Comment: The first line in here is dangerous. If there is no "id" in the query string, it will result in a javascript error.

Comment: I corrected. It's a valid JS idea, the OP didn't ask for a full solution. :P